# ScalaTest's equivalent of JUnit's suites?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I'm new to Scala. Coming from Java, I'm use to group/bundle my test classes in (JUnit) suites, in a hierarchical matter (suites within suites).

I'm looking for an alternative to this in ScalaTest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Suite can contain nested Suites. These are returned from the nestedSuites lifecyle method. You can use the Suites class to do this:

http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.Suites

If you want to disable discovery of the nested suites, you can use the @DoNotDiscover annotation:

http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover

Answer (score 0):

Both [`FunSpec`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/#org.scalatest.FunSpec) and [`FreeSpec`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/#org.scalatest.FreeSpec) allow nesting as much as you want. Examples from http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/selecting_a_style:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class SetSpec extends FunSpec {

  describe("A Set") {
    describe("when empty") {
      it("should have size 0") {
        assert(Set.empty.size == 0)
      }

      it("should produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked") {
        intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
          Set.empty.head
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // just add more describe calls
}
```

and

```
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec

class SetSpec extends FreeSpec {

  "A Set" - {
    "when empty" - {
      "should have size 0" in {
        assert(Set.empty.size == 0)
      }

      "should produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked" in {
        intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
          Set.empty.head
        }
      }
    }

    // add more - calls
  }

  // add more - calls
}
```

Comment: Alexey, I think the question is about having different specs, like `SetSpec` and `ListSpec` and being able to create a suite called `CollectionsSpec`.

Comment: @Eric Yes, but that's the only way to achieve nesting with JUnit (AFAIK). ScalaTest allows this approach as well.